# eBay API returns low resolution thumbnails

Tags: javascript, html, json, ebay-api

I figured adding `&outputSelector=GalleryInfo` to the url would provide a higher resolution thumbnail, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm new to JSON, and the tutorial isn't very clear on the exact syntax to add to the URL to make this happen. Thanks!

```
<script>
function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root)
{
  var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
  var html = [];
  html.push('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"><tbody>');

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)  
  {
    var item     = items[i];
    var title    = item.title;
    var pic      = item.galleryURL;
    var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
    if (null != title && null != viewitem)
    {
      html.push(
        '<tr id="api_microposts"><td>'
         + '<img src="' + pic + '" border="0" width="190">' + '<a href="' + viewitem + '" target="_blank">' + title + 
         '</a></td></tr>');
    }
  }
  html.push('</tbody></table>');
  document.getElementById("api").innerHTML = html.join("");




// Define global variable for the URL filter
var urlfilter = "";


// Generates an indexed URL snippet from the array of item filters
function  buildURLArray() {
  // Iterate through each filter in the array
  for(var i=0; i<filterarray.length; i++) {
    //Index each item filter in filterarray
    var itemfilter = filterarray[i];
    // Iterate through each parameter in each item filter
    for(var index in itemfilter) {
      // Check to see if the parameter has a value (some don't)
      if (itemfilter[index] !== "") {
        if (itemfilter[index] instanceof Array) {
          for(var r=0; r<itemfilter[index].length; r++) {
          var value = itemfilter[index][r];
          urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "\(" + r + "\)=" + value ;
          }
        }
        else {
          urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "=" + itemfilter[index];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}  // End buildURLArray() function

// Execute the function to build the URL filter
buildURLArray(filterarray);

url += urlfilter;



}
</script>


<!--
Use the value of your appid for the appid parameter below.
-->

<script src=http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=*APP ID GOES HERE*&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.12.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=6&outputSelector=GalleryInfo&outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)=New&itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value=450.00&itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value=350.00&itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value=FixedPrice&keywords=Moto%20x%2016gb>

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eBay API isn't pulling high res photos for listings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721404/ebay-api-isnt-pulling-high-res-photos-for-listings)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for the galleryPlusPictureURL: http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/types/SearchItem.html#galleryPlusPictureURL